# multiple selectInput values create unexpected dplyr (postgres) behavior

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I have a lovely Shiny app which accepts selectInput values, queries a postgres DB, and outputs a graph. (It's a simple interface, but hard to reproduce here due to dplyr database connections!)

Today I changed the first selectInput value to multiple=TRUE; updated the variable being passed to the database to be %in% the list returned by the modified control; and all heck broke loose.

1. Before I select a value the control is null, so I am greeted by the Shiny red "ERROR: RS-DBI driver ... " telling me my query "IN ()" isn't valid
2. When only one value is selected I get a syntax error, ""locationID" IN 'A1080330' "
3. I can solve this by putting parentheses around the list returned...
   locationID %in% (input$rtnLocid)
4. however this creates a new "operator doesn't exist" error when I select more than one list item because of the added parentheses:  " IN (('A1080330', 'B...'))

I think what's going on is the postgres driver always wants SQL list values in parentheses when using IN (some DBs may be more lenient here); adding the parentheses fixes the first selection; the added parentheses break the postgres driver again when multi-select is on.

Can anyone else using Shiny / postgres verify this behavior?

Regards,
Jeff

Update: @Steven pointed out this info link in the comments which I hadn't found when I posted: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/511

Comment: Here is a question about this `%in%` issue in R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789498/filter-multiple-values-in-postgresql-database-with-dplyr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way the query is constructed when you select only **one** element and use the `IN` operator. The `dplyr` translation to  `SQL` does not add the proper parenthesis and thus, fail. This issue was discussed at length [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/511).

One way to work around this is to pass a different instruction to `filter()` when `length` of input is equal to 1 (see example below).

---

Here's what is happening:

```
tbl(mydb, "iris") %>%
  filter(Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor")) %>%
  .$query
```

Gives the proper `SQL` query syntax:

```
<Query> SELECT "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"
FROM "iris"
WHERE "Species" IN ('setosa', 'versicolor')
<PostgreSQLConnection>
```

And, if executed, gives the expected:

```
#Source: postgres 9.3.13 [elm@127.0.0.1:5432/csvdump]
#From: iris [100 x 5]
#Filter: Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor") 
#
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#          (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)   (chr)
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#..          ...         ...          ...         ...     ...
```

Let see what happens if you try to pass a single element:

```
tbl(mydb, "iris") %>%
  filter(Species %in% "setosa") %>%
  .$query
```

The query will be:

```
<Query> SELECT "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"
FROM "iris"
WHERE "Species" IN 'setosa'
<PostgreSQLConnection>
```

Which, if executed, will result in the following error:

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or
>   near "'setosa'" LINE 3: WHERE "Species" IN 'setosa') AS "master"
>                              ^ )

That's because for a single element, the `dplyr` translation to `SQL` query doesn't add the proper parenthesis. Notice how it's `'setosa'` instead of `('setosa')`.

To circumvent that, we can do:

```
if(length(input$Species) == 1) { 
  tbl(mydb, "iris") %>% 
    filter(Species == input$Species) %>% 
}
```

Which will build a syntactically valid `SQL` query:

```
<Query> SELECT "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species" 
FROM "iris" 
WHERE "Species" = 'setosa' 
<PostgreSQLConnection>
```

---

The following example works around this issue. Here I simply instruct the app to pass `filter(Species == ...)` if `input$Species` is of `length` 1 and `filter(Species %in% ...)` otherwise.

[image]

---

**ShinyApp**

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  selectedQuery <- reactive({

    if(length(input$Species) == 1) { 
      tbl(mydb, "iris") %>% 
        filter(Species == input$Species) %>% 
        .$query
    }
    else(
      tbl(mydb, "iris") %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$Species) %>% 
        .$query
      )

  })

  selectedData <- reactive({

    if(length(input$Species) == 1) {
      tbl(mydb, "iris") %>% 
        filter(Species == input$Species) %>% 
        data.frame
    }
    else(
      tbl(mydb, "iris") %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$Species) %>% 
        data.frame
      )
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot2::qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = selectedData(), color = Species)
  })

  output$query <- renderPrint({
    selectedQuery()
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Species", "Species", 
                  tbl(mydb, "iris") %>% 
                    data.frame %>% 
                    .$Species %>% 
                    unique, 
                  selected = "setosa", multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("query"),
      plotOutput("plot")
      )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Steven -- I'm tweaking this now (I'm not at-ease with R yet, particularly pipes, sorry for the delay).

The confusing bit for me is I CAN write a SQL query using IN with only one criteria -- here's [an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a0a9/2).

Comment: I think what was a little surprising for me was that dplyr implicitely controls %in% rather than letting the programmer decide between == and %in% to better match SQL.

In SQL this is valid: 
    <Query>SELECT "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length",  "Petal.Width", "Species"
    FROM "iris"
    WHERE "Species" IN ('setosa')

Comment: @Jeff Sorry if I wasn't explicit enough. The problem is not that a `SQL` query with `IN` and a single element is not possible, it's the syntax conversion `dplyr` does. I'll edit to be more explicit.

Comment: solid, thanks. Thanks for the github link too.

I'll add a kludge for a slider (of integers) below; a different issue with the same origin. This "works", but falls into the "must be a better way" category.

    crit <- as.numeric(input$int) #slider input from 1 to 50
    slider.range <- as.integer(unlist(input$int))
    if (slider.range[1] == slider.range[2]) {
        crit = crit #no change
    }
    else {
      crit = slider.range[1]:slider.range[2]
    }

Answer (score 3):

Although Steven's answer is perfectly fine, I use a slightly different approach that allows you to use a single pipe. This is convenient when you want to perform other operations as well.

This is what the selectedData reactive would look like:

```
selectedData <- reactive({
  tbl(mydb, "iris") %>% 
  {
    if(length(input$Species) == 1) 
      filter(., Species == input$Species)
    else
      filter(., Species %in% input$Species)
  } %>%
    data.frame %>%
    mutate() %>%
    etc... 
})
```